# CreateBitmap() returns upside down image

Tags: c++, file, winapi, bitmap

I load my saved Bitmap's bits array. (and BITMAPINFOHEADER structure).

```
HBITMAP Filemanager::LoadNextImageFromMyFile(HANDLE file)
{
HDC hdc = GetDC(father->hWindow->_hwnd);
DWORD dwTmp; 
BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr;
ReadFile(file,&hdr,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),&dwTmp,NULL);
BITMAPINFOHEADER pbih; 
ReadFile(file, &pbih,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) 
    + hdr.bfReserved1 * sizeof (RGBQUAD),&dwTmp,NULL);
LPBYTE lpBits = (LPBYTE) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, pbih.biSizeImage);
BYTE* hp = lpBits;
ReadFile(file,hp,pbih.biSizeImage, &dwTmp, NULL);
return CreateBitmap(pbih.biWidth,pbih.biHeight,pbih.biPlanes,pbih.biBitCount, hp);;
}
```

I get upside down image. How can i fix it? (i think that reversing bitsArray will be a solution, but maybe there is better way?)

Comment: Bitmaps are normally stored upside down.  If the height is positive it's assumed to be bottom up and if it is negative then it is top down.

Comment: Call `CreateDIBitmap` and use either positive or negative height in `BITMAPV5HEADER` to get your bitmap the right way up.

Comment: As far as I remember the Windows API documentation said (in Windows NT 3.x times) that "CreateBitmap" should not be used for color bitmaps. You should use CreateCompatibleBitmap and SetDiBits instead. I do not know why the bitmap is turned around because in .BMP files a bitmap is already stored upside down and Windows API functions require a Bitmap to be stored upside down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call CreateDIBitmap and use either positive or negative height in BITMAPV5HEADER to get your bitmap the right way up. –  David Heffernan 37 mins ago

Comment: So, that helped did it?